# concatenar JS de forma correcta para una variable

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando acceder al valor de un input, por el id.

**getElementById**

```
let inputValue = document.getElementById("dom2").value;
```

Cuando ejecuto esa linea, ejecuta de manera correcta.

Pero cuando intento ejecutarla de manera dinámica, me genera un error de acceso `null`, creo que estoy concatenando de manera incorrecta, pero no he podido solucionar.

Por parámetro yo recibo un numero, que llamo obj.

cuando imprimo el obj.

```
console.log(obj);
```

este me imprime  `1` o `2` o `3` o `4` o `5`, etc.

y el nombre de mis `ids` son `dom1`,`dom2`, `dom3`, `dom4`, etc..

Así que intento concatenar así.

```
let inputValue = document.getElementById("dom"+obj).value;
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

intenté:

```
let id='dom' + obj ;
let inputValue = document.getElementById('"'+id+'"').value;
```

pero tampoco lo he logrado.

```
 let id="dom" + obj ;
                    let inputValue = document.getElementById(`dom${obj}`).value;
```

error//

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intenté

```
 let inputValue = document.getElementById( ` dom{id}` ).value;
```

error.

intenté:

```
let inputValue = document.getElementById('dom{id}').value;
```

he puesto el codigo en :

https://jsfiddle.net/5nkLd72v/3/

Comment: haz probado utilizando los bactiks asi -> "getElementById( ` dom{id}` ).value;"

Comment: Puedes reproducir el código aquí en la pregunta? así descartamos que no haya ningun error de typeo

Comment: actualizé el codigo, arriba, para mostrar el codigo que hice.

Comment: No utilices imágenes. Es mucho más fácil para nosotros asistirte si escribes el código. También, puedes utilizar [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) para mostrarnos un ejemplo de tu código.

Comment: Gracias, he duplicado el codigo en: 
https://jsfiddle.net/981jt57v/20/

Comment: Vi algunos fallos en tu jsFiddle, primero no tienes `jquery`, segundo tus id que utilizas dentro del js esta mal todos dicen `dom1`, luego solo concatenar con un + y funciona, según lo que veo. https://jsfiddle.net/carlosuv92/ptzcswmd/

Comment: Gracias @FelipeUrcia si, en realidad cada id es diferente, fue un error de transcripcion, igual en tu codigo, si le das click a un check, sale error, este no trae la informacion del input. marca error

Comment: @wil toda la razón, ya lo corregí, no agregue jQuery. O me equivoco, porque tu código es jQuery. Actualice el link https://jsfiddle.net/carlosuv92/ptzcswmd/1/

Comment: Gracias! tendré que estudiar entre js y jquery :(, la verdad es que voy averiguando en internet poco a poco y voy agregando cosas a mi proyecto.
como agrego la libreria jQuery a mi pagina html por cdn ?

Comment: ahi en tu codigo, revisando encontre que el jQuery que usaste es:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js

espero que con eso me funcione, gracias.

Comment: No veo el error, acabo de ejecutar la muestra publicada en fiddle después de agregar jQuery 3.4.1 y funciona perfectamente. De todas formas pienso que podrías usar el id como parámetro en lugar del número: check('dom1') en lugar de check(1)  y comprobar si sigue produciéndose el error.

Comment: gracias @Juan y a felipeUrcia, ya quedó todo funcional, me di cuenta que estaba mezclando js con jQuery, algo que no sabia. y ya pude hacerlo funcionar, por otro lado en check(1), en el comentario aclaro que  ese 1, sera dinamico. pero por el momento ps lo creé manualmente. muchas gracias a todos por su apoyo.